# How to truncate file to maximum number of characters (not bytes)

Tags: text-processing

How can I truncate a (UTF-8 encoded) text file to given number of characters? I don't care about line lengths and the cut can be in the middle of word.

- `cut` seems to operate on lines, but I want a whole file.
- `head -c` uses bytes, not characters.

Comment: Note that the GNU implementation of `cut` still doesn't support multi-byte characters. If it did, you could do `cut -zc-1234 | tr -d '\0'`.

Comment: How do you want to handle emojis? Some are more that one character... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502486/how-to-get-correct-length-of-a-string-containing-emojis-in-c-sharp

Comment: What's a character?  some symbols use several code points,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some systems have a `truncate` command that truncates files to a number of *bytes* (not characters).

I don't know of any that truncate to a number of characters, though you could resort to `perl` which is installed by default on most systems:

### perl

```
perl -Mopen=locale -ne '
  BEGIN{$/ = \1234} truncate STDIN, tell STDIN; last' <> "$file"
```

- With `-Mopen=locale`, we use the locale's notion of what characters are (so in locales using the UTF-8 charset, that's UTF-8 encoded characters). Replace with `-CS` if you want I/O to be decoded/encoded in UTF-8 regardless of the locale's charset.
- `$/ = \1234`: we set the record separator to a reference to an integer which is a way to specify records of fixed length (in number of *characters*).
- then upon reading the first record, we truncate stdin in place (so at the end of the first record) and exit.

### GNU sed

With GNU `sed`, you could do (assuming the file doesn't contain NUL characters or sequences of bytes which don't form valid characters -- both of which should be true of text files):

```
sed -Ez -i -- 's/^(.{1234}).*/\1/' "$file"
```

But that's far less efficient, as it reads the file in full and stores it whole in memory, and writes a new copy.

### GNU awk

Same with GNU `awk`:

```
awk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk -v RS='^$' -e '
  {printf "%s", substr($0, 1, 1234)}' -E /dev/null "$file"
```

- `-e code -E /dev/null "$file"` being one way to pass arbitrary file names to `gawk`
- `RS='^$'`: [slurp mode](/q/304457).

**Do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`

## Shell builtins

With `ksh93`, `bash` or `zsh` (with shells other than `zsh`, assuming the content doesn't contain NUL bytes):

```
content=$(cat < "$file" && echo .) &&
  content=${content%.} &&
  printf %s "${content:0:1234}" > "$file"
```

With `zsh`:

```
read -k1234 -u0 s < $file &&
  printf %s $s > $file
```

Or:

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
mapfile[$file]=${mapfile[$file][1,1234]}
```

With `ksh93` or `bash` (beware [it's bogus for multi-byte characters in several versions of `bash`](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg19559.html)):

```
IFS= read -rN1234 s < "$file" &&
  printf %s "$s" > "$file"
```

`ksh93` can also truncate the file in place instead of rewriting it with its `<>;` redirection operator:

```
IFS= read -rN1234 0<>; "$file"
```

### iconv + head

To *print* the first 1234 characters, another option could be to convert to an encoding with a fixed number of bytes per character like `UTF32BE`/`UCS-4`:

```
iconv -t UCS-4 < "$file" | head -c "$((1234 * 4))" | iconv -f UCS-4
```

`head -c` is not standard, but fairly common. A standard equivalent would be `dd bs=1 count="$((1234 * 4))"` but would be less efficient, as it would read the input and write the output one byte at a time¹. `iconv` is a standard command but the encoding names are not standardized, so you might find systems without `UCS-4`

### Notes

In any case, though the output would have at most 1234 characters, it may end up not being valid text, as it would possibly end in a non-delimited line.

Also note that while those solutions wouldn't cut text in the middle of a character, they could break it in the middle of a *grapheme* , like a `é` expressed as U+0065 U+0301 (a `e` followed by a combining acute accent), or Hangul syllable graphemes in their decomposed forms.

---

<sup>¹ and on pipe input you can't use `bs` values other than 1 reliably unless you use the `iflag=fullblock` GNU extension, as `dd` could do short reads if it reads the pipe quicker than `iconv` fills it</sup>

Comment: could do `dd bs=1234 count=4`

Comment: @Jasen, that would not be  reliable. See edit.

Comment: Wow!  you would be handy to have nearby!  I thought I knew a lot of handy Unix commands but this is an incredible list of great options.

Answer (score 5):

If you know that the text file contains Unicode encoded as UTF-8 you have to first decode the UTF-8 to get a sequence of Unicode character entities and split those.

I'd choose Python 3.x for the job.

With Python 3.x the function [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) has an extra key-word argument `encoding=` for reading [text-files](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-text-file). The description of method [io.TextIOBase.read()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.read) looks promising.

So using Python 3 it would look like this:

```
truncated = open('/path/to/file.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf-8').read(1000)
```

Obviously a real tool would add command-line arguments, error handling etc.

With Python 2.x you could implement your own file-like object and decode the input file line-by-line.

Comment: Yeah, i could do that. But it's for CI build machines, so I'd like to rarther use some standard Linux command.

Comment: Whatever "standard Linux" means on your Linux flavour...

Comment: Indeed, Python, some version of it anyway, is pretty standard these days.

Comment: I've already edited my answer with snippet for Python 3 which can explicitly process text-files.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl6)

Raku provides high-level support for Unicode, built-in. Except for filehandle names, graphemes are converted to the Unicode Consortium's "[Normalization Form C](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/)" (NFC) by default. Below is an example with Emoticons.

Sample Input:

```
~$ raku -e 'for (0..8) -> $i { $_.[0..$i].join.put given "\x1F600".."\x1F64F"};' > emoticons_0-to-8.txt
~$ cat emoticons_0-to-8.txt
```

Read `54` characters¹  from the filehandle using `readchars`:²

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my $file = "emoticons_0-to-8.txt".IO; given $file.open { put .readchars: 54; .close; };'
```

Reading `54` characters from the filehandle prints out the file including the `\n` newline on line 9. Reading `55` characters is the same as `54`; reading `53` characters from the filehandle prints out the file omitting the `\n` newline on line 9 (data not shown). Hence we can have some confidence that multibyte characters are being handled correctly.

Presently, Raku cannot `truncate` files like Perl, nor do `-i.bak` in-place file editing/backup. Maybe the most robust way to truncate a file in Raku is to write out (i.e. `spurt`) to a separate `_bak` backup file, `unlink` the original if the `$bak` backup `:e` exists and is a `:f` file, and finally `copy` the backup over the original.

Below we truncate our emoticon file to 52 characters, deleting the final (purple) emoticon. Generalized file names:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'given "/path/to/original.txt".IO.open {   \
            my $bak = /path/to/original_bak.txt";     \
            spurt($bak, .readchars(52), createonly => True);  \
            unlink($_) if $bak.IO:e & $bak.IO:f;              \
            copy($bak, $_, createonly => True); .close; };'
```

Sample Output (switching to `zsh` which shows the EOF with `%`):

```perl
~$ zsh
~% cat emoticons_0-to-8.txt








%
```

---

<sup>¹ Use Gauss' calculation (add `\n` per line): `raku -e 'say (10 * 4.5) + 9;'` gives `54`.

² Rakudo compiler defaults to a max of `65536` characters for `readchars`, if no character value is supplied.</sup>

https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode
https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/
https://docs.raku.org/type/IO/Path#File_test_operators
https://docs.raku.org/routine/readchars
https://raku.org

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to add another approach. Probably not the best performance wise, and much longer, but easy to understand:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

chars="$1"
ifile="$2"
result=$(cat "$ifile")
rcount=$(echo -n "$result" | wc -m)

while [ $rcount -ne $chars ]; do
        result=${result::-1}
        rcount=$(echo -n "$result" | wc -m)
done

echo "$result"
```

Invoke it with `$ ./scriptname <desired chars> <input file>`.

This removes the last char one by one until the goal is met, which seems really bad performance wise especially for bigger files. I just wanted to present this as an idea to show more possibilities.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely horrible for performance.  For a file of length n, `wc` counts on the order of O(n^2) total bytes for a target point half way into the file.  It should be possible to binary-search instead of linear search by using a variable that you increase or decrease, like  `echo -n "${result::-$chop}" | wc -m` or something.  (And while you're at it, make it safe even if the file contents start with `-e` or something, maybe using `printf`).  But you still won't beat methods that only look at each input character once, so probably not worth it.

Comment: You're definitely right, more of a technical answer rather than a practical answer. You could also reverse it to add char by char to the `$result` until it matches the desired length, but if desired length is a high number it's just as inefficient.

Comment: You could start close to the right place by starting with `$desired_chars` bytes at the low end, or maybe `4*$desired_chars` at the high end.  But still I think it's best to use something else entirely.